# Why wouldn't polymorphism work in this case?

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25);
```

The method call `aThing.intValue()` is a compiler error. Why doesn't polymorphism work in this case?

Also there's a related statement in my textbook that is a bit convoluted:

> The type of reference, not the type of the object referenced, determines that operations can be performed.

Can you briefly elaborate on that?

Where as `Computer[] labComputers = new Computer[10];` works with polymorphism

```
public class Computer {
    int ram;
    public Computer(int rm){
        ram= rm;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String result = "ram is " + ram;
        return result;
    }
}


public class Notebook extends Computer{
int size;
public Notebook(int rm, int sz){
    super(rm);
    size = sz;
}
@Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = super.toString() + " size is " + size;
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Added**:
I believe somewhere in the middle, there would be

```
labComputer[1] = new Notebook(2,15);
labComputer[2] = new Computer(2);
```

For the method call `labComputers[1].toString()`, polymophism ensures that the correct `toString` is called.  In my mind `labComputer[1] = new Notebook(2,15);` is equivalent to `Object o = new Integer(25);`. But polymorphism worked for my Computer example not in the Object-Integer example. Why?

Comment: Both `Notebook` and `Computer` have a `toString()` method, therefore you can call it on either of them. But from `Object` and `Integer`, only `Integer` has an `intValue()` method, so you can't call it on `Object`.

Comment: @Radu well, the Object variable was referenced by an Integer though, just like `Computer` was referenced by Notebook (`labComputer[1] = new Notebook(2,15);`)

Comment: Indeed, and if you keep it an `Integer`, you can call its `intValue()` method. But if you assign it to an `Object` variable, then it ceases to be an `Integer`, and therefore the `intValue()` method won't be accessible anymore (the actual data is still there, the information is not lost, it's just hidden and inaccessible). The same thing would happen if you were to define a, say, `closeLid()` method in the `Notebook` class (like `intValue()` in the `Integer` class). You'll see that you won't be able to call it on `labComputers[i]`, because they're now `Computers`, they ceased to be `Notebook`s.

Comment: @Radu I see it now, the `closeLid()` method indeed did not show. but how do you explain the output `ram is 2 size is 9`  yet the **size** is outputted, how in the world did i access the `toString` in `Notebook` if they ceased to be `Notebook`s?

Comment: Even though it's not a `Notebook` anymore, the data is still there. The methods are still there. `Notebook` overwrites the `toString()` method defined by `Computer`. It's called the same thing, that's why you can still call it on a `Computer` object, but it does what `Notebook` made it do. So the object really is still a `Notebook`, but it's treated as a `Computer`.

Comment: As an analogy, think about the real world. If you connect through Remote Desktop to a computer, you don't know what the type of that computer is. You can do with it whatever you can do with any kind of computer. If you look at how much RAM it has, it will tell you. But you won't be able to know if it has a lid or not. That information is hidden to you. Therefore, you don't know if you can close it either. If you go to see the actual computer in person, you will immediately know that it's a notebook and you will be able to close the lid.

Comment: So even though the computer is really a notebook, using Remote Desktop you interacted with it as if it was just another computer. It acted exactly like it would normally act, and you could only use the subset of functions common to any other computer. To you, it wasn't a notebook, it was a computer. But behind the scenes, it's really a notebook. It does have a lid, the lid can be closed. But not unless you *know* that it's a notebook and you have access to it.

Comment: ok, so yes i think this is going back to the quote from the book "The type of reference, not the type of the object referenced, determines what operations can be performed." so that means `Computer labComputer` determines the type?

Comment: Exactly. When you say `Computer`, you tell the compiler that the type of the variable is `Computer`. From now on, when you use that variable, you will be able to call what `Computer` defines. It's like a filter. You hide the extra functionality of the `Notebook`. You can assign to that variable anything that is of type `Computer`. So any `Computer`, any `Notebook`, or anything else that extends `Computer`, but you will only be able to call `toString()`, not anything extra that they define.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18024/discussion-between-user133466-and-radu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work because your variable is from `Object` class, so you can only use methods in the  `Object` class. If you want to use it as an `Integer`, you should first do a (down) type casting:

```
Integer aInteger = (Integer)aThing;
//it could maybe work
aInteger.intValue();
```

Now, why could *maybe* work? Because downcasting could throw a ClassCastException if the type casting won't work.

Based in your example, I would post a basic code to show how polymophism works:

```
class Animal {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm an animal and I can move.");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    //this means a Cat would change the move behavior from the Animal instance
    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm a cat and I can move.");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    //this means a Cat would change the move behavior from the Animal instance
    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm a dog and I like to run.");
    }
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("I can bark!");
    }
}

public class AnimalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //it will take the behavior of the Animal class reference
         Animal animal = new Animal();
         //it will take the behavior of the Cat class reference
         Animal cat = new Cat();
         //it will take the behavior of the Dog class reference
         Animal dog = new Dog();
         //this will invoke the Animal#move method
         animal.move();
         //this will invoke the Cat#move method because it was overriden in the Cat class
         cat.move();
         //this will invoke the Dog#move method because it was overriden in the Dog class
         dog.move();
         //this line won't compile if uncommented because not all animals can bark.
         //dog.bark();
         //if you want to make the dog barks, then you should use the downcasting
         ((Dog)dog).bark();
         //note that this will only work for Dog class reference, not for any other class
         //uncomment this line and the code will compile but throw a ClassCastException
         //((Dog)cat).bark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it would make his point better if some of your animals had specific methods that are not inherited from Animal?

Comment: @user133466 I didn't say that but prefer to post my example to show the differences between the super class and the children class to show how polymorphism works. Also, overriding the `toString` is another example, because that method belongs to `Object` class. Remove the `toString` implementation in your computer class and test your code again in order to get another example.

Comment: i've added 2 lines to supplement my example `labComputer[1] = new Notebook(@params etc etc);
labComputer[2] = new Computer(@params etc etc);` would be declared somewhere along the code. In my mind `labComputer[1] = new Notebook(@params etc etc);` is equivalent to `Object o = new Integer(25);`. But polymorphism worked for my example not in the Object-Integer example. (I sticked with my example because I believe, after reading the Animal example you gave, my Computer example is slightly different, i'm abit more comfortable there.... i hope you'd understand

Comment: @user133466 yes, my example covers more that what you wanted to learn. If you want to understand polymorphism, comment the `toString` method in your `Computer` class, but leave it in the `Notebook` class.

Comment: i got Notebook@71e2b67c size is 9, that is so weird....it was supposed to print notebook ram 2 size 9

Comment: @user133466 it's not weird because it's using the `Object#toString()` method. Given this example, if you uncomment the `toString` method, when printing the object it will use the override method. That's how polymorphism works.

Comment: `Object` variable was referenced by an `Integer` though, just like `Computer` was referenced by `Notebook` (`labComputer[1] = new Notebook(2,15);`) I got an output `ram is 2 size is 9` for `labComputer[1].toString();`  the size is outputted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18023/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-user133466)

Comment: with a Down typecasting (`Integer aInteger = (Integer)aThing;`), it's like declaring `Integer aThing;`again? (then `Integer aInteger = aThing`)

Comment: when you say "class reference", it means class methods correct?

Comment: @user133466 it's similar but not the same. Note that when you do down typecasting, you can use the class reference, a super class on the tree of the class reference or any interface implemented by the class reference. It's not re-declaring the variable type, just what methods can call from the class typecasted. Example: `Object o = new Integer(5); Integer i = (Integer)o; Number n = (Number)o; Comparable<Integer> ci = (Comparable<Integer>)o;` because `class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>`.

Comment: @user133466 after doing the type cast, you could use any methods in the casted class or interface.

Comment: in the example `Integer aInteger = (Integer)aThing;` you said "you can use the class reference, a super class on the tree of the class reference" the class reference in this case would be `aInteger` (not `aThing`) and a super class on the tree of this class would `Object` correct?

Comment: Luiggi what's the best way to reach you?

Comment: @user133466 profile edited. It's strange because there is an email section in it, maybe it's hidden for other people.

Comment: @user133466 I'm working and can't chat right now, sorry. If it's urgent, send me an email and I'll answer you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5):

Because even though `Integer` is an `Object`, `Object` is not an `Integer` and therefore it doesn't have `Integer`'s methods, only `Object`'s.

---

> The type of reference, not the type of the object referenced, determines that operations can be performed.

By that they mean that even though the object that is referenced contains more functionality, if the *type* of the reference is different from the type of the object, then only the functionality of they *type of the reference* will be available.

In the following:

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25);
```

the type of `aThing` is declared as `Object`. Even though the implementation contains more than that, whatever else the implementation contains is not visible anymore, because the *type* of the variable is not `Integer`, but `Object`. Both `Object` and `Integer` have methods in common, but you can only access the ones provided by `Object` from now on, because nobody other than you know that this is really an `Integer`, not just an `Object`.

---

In the second example they mean that even though both `Object` and `Integer` have methods in common, when you call one of the methods, the method of the actual type will be called. So in this case, if you call `toString()` on `aThing`, you will call `Integer`'s `toString()` method, not `Object`'s. Therefore this is only an access issue. The fact that you declare it as an `Object` doesn't mean that you will get `Object`'s methods to respond to calls, it only means that whatever methods that are present in `Integer` and not in `Object` will just be unavailable.

---

Example:

```
class Computer {
    public int getInstalledOperatingSystems() { return 3; }
}

class Desktop extends Computer {
    public String getShapeOfCase() { ... }
}

class Notebook extends Computer {
    public int getInstalledOperatingSystems() { return 1; }
    public String getBrand() { ... }
    public void closeLid() { ... }
}
```

Now let's create a `Notebook`:

```
Notebook n = new Notebook();
```

Suppose that you have the following method:

```
public String showStatistics(Computer computer) {
    result = "Operating systems: " + computer.getInstalledOperatingSystems();
    return result;
}
```

If you call this method with the `Notebook` you defined above:

```
showStatistics(n);
```

then the method will receive the `Notebook`, because a `Notebook` is a `Computer`. It can call the `Notebook`'s `getInstalledOperatingSystems()` method, because any `Computer` has that method. When it calls it, it will receive `1` as a result, because `Notebook` overrides `Computer`'s implementation. But `showStatistics()` will not be able to call any other method that `Notebook` provides, because it doesn't know that it's being passed a `Notebook`. For all it cares, it has a `Computer`, and it doesn't know of any other method that a `Computer` doesn't have.

You can very well send it a `Desktop` instead, or maybe tomorrow you will create a `GamingComputer` that extends `Desktop` or a `Server` class that extends `Computer`. You can send that as well. But `showStatistics()` will not have access to any of `Server`'s specific, specialized methods, because `showStatistics()` doesn't *know* that it's looking at a `Server`. It wasn't even invented when `showStatistics()` was written.

This is consistent with the statement that even though a `Server` is always a `Computer`, a `Computer` is not always a `Server`.

---

You can check though. So if you *know* that you might be passed in a `Notebook`, not only a computer, you can look for that and you can even call `Notebook`'s methods, but you have to be sure that you're looking at a `Notebook`:

```
if (computer instanceof Notebook) {
    // this is definitely a Notebook, so you can assure the compiler
    // of that explicitly, by using a cast
    Notebook notebook = (Notebook) computer;

    result += "This isn't just a generic computer, it's actually a notebook! ";

    // now that you have a variable of type Notebook, you can call
    // whatever Notebook provides
    result += "It's produced by: " + notebook.getBrand();
}
```

Comment: but it is referenced to an `Integer`!

Comment: True, but if you make it an `Object`, you're practically removing access to all the functionality unrelated to an `Object`. If you want to access that functionality again, you need to make it an `Integer` again, by casting.

Comment: @user133466 It is obvious in this case that it refers to an Integer. However it is easy to construct cases where it isn't obvious what it refers to, e.g. an Object returned by a library that was already compiled when this source code was being compiled, and the compiler can't have different rules for one situation than for another.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way, a dog is an object and a dog class might have methods such as

`dog.bark()`

If you cast Dog up the hierarchy to an Object, it becomes less specific.

`Object o = dog;`

Now all you know is that o is an object, you do not know what kind of objects and therefore you cannot know if this object can bark.

When you move UP the hierarchy you almost always lose functionality by being less specific about what you have.

Comment: no, I would assign it like this `Object o = New Dog();` why wouldn't this work?

Comment: You could do that, and you would still be able to store the dog as an object...but you would be unable to make the object bark because all you would know about Object o is that it's an object.  It could also be a cat, and cats do not bark!

Comment: can you take a look at my Computer example? I have supplied the classes there, why did polymorphism worked in that case? it correctly printed the right `toString` (`Computer[] labComputers = new Computer[10];` was declared UP the hierarchy)

Comment: toString is a method of Object.  That means ALL objects (cats, dogs, laptops, whatever) have the toString method.  Since all objects can toString you can do that.  But all objects cannot bark (nor do all objects have an integer value).

Comment: if what you said is true, `labcomputer[i].toString()` should print computer specs *only*. because it was declared like `Computer[] labComputers` so it's up the hierarchy..

Comment: There is something called a Virtual Method Table.  This table keeps track of the lowest (most specific) implementation of a function.  So even though we are higher in the hierarchy, we still know which IMPLEMENTATIONS of methods we should use.  The method, however, still has to be a member of the object we have an instance of.

Comment: I'm quite new to programming, I haven't heard of the VMT you talked about, but In my mind `labComputer[1] = new Notebook(@params etc etc);` is equivalent to `Object o = new Integer(25);`. But polymorphism worked for my example not in the Object-Integer example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18022/discussion-between-user133466-and-ben)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to be told what type it should expect the object to be, so it can look up the class and see if the method is legit.

So you can say `Object aThing = new Integer(25);` but then you'd want to say `int thingValue = (Integer)aThing.intValue();`

If you have a MySubClass object that is is a subclass of MyClass, and you want to call a method defined in MyClass (even if reimplemented in MySubClass) you could say:

```
Object myObject = new MySubClass();
int someValue = (MyClass)myObject.methodInMyObject();
```